# How to create/select a unique Identifier OID in case I have a spatial view and none of the fields or their combination can be unique

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, esri-geodatabase

How to create/select a unique Identifier OID in case I have a table view in oracle and none of the fields or their combination can be unique. The process of selecting OID is described [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//019v00000005000000) and [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//019v00000016000000).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only does a registered rowid column need to be INTEGER (32-bit), POSITIVE, NON-ZERO, NOT NULL and UNIQUE, it also needs to be reproducible on subsequent invocations.  It is not possible to manufacture a field on the fly which meets this reproducibility requirement.

Therefore the only way to generate a rowid for such a non-unique view is to populate a table with whatever combination of attributes *are* unique, add a sequence-fed NUMBER(38) value to that table, and then join the new table into the view.

It may be possible to produce a join which performs adequately for some use cases, but it is unlikely to perform well in all use cases. For this reason, it is highly advised to *find* or *make* a field in the existing tables which *does* meet the required characteristics, or to manifest the view as a table (updated as frequently as necessary), where a reproducible value can be persisted.  (The side effect will be improved performance over the source view in all use cases.)